# Firebase - Putting files in multiple directories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firebase

I'm attempting to organize my project to make it more maintainable. I have a large number of html templates and am forced to put them all in the public directory. I really wanted to organize it like this

```
public directory
  views
    index.html
    register.html
    terms.html
    privacy.html
    support.html
  stylesheets
    styles.css
  scripts
    script.js
    authentication.js
```

but instead it looks like this

```
public
  index.html
  register.html
  terms.html
  privacy.html
  support.html
  script.js
  authentication.js
  styles.css
```

Here is my `firebase.json` file

```
   {
  "firebase": "funmathgame",
  "public": "mathgame",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Here is the error message I get

> Page Not Found
>
> The file does not exist and there was no `index.html` found in the current directory or `404.html` in the root directory.
>
> Why am I seeing this?
>
> You may have deployed the wrong directory for your application. Check your `firebase.json` and make sure the **public** directory is pointing to a directory that contains an `index.html` file.
>
> You can also add a `404.html` in the root of your site to replace this page with a custom error page.

The first structure is better because it separates the code. This structure works whenever I run the files in my text editor. However, it does not work whenever I deploy to firebase.

As an example, this is how I would reference my stylesheets

```
<head>
  <title>Frequently Asked Questions</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'> 
  </link>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../stylesheets/styles.css'></link>
```

In the above directory structure, I am in the `public/views` directory. I use `..` to move back one directory into the public directory and then forward into the stylesheets directory. However, here my `index.html` file is not in the public directory, but rather the `public/views` directory.

I have looked at the Firebase website, but still can't find any ideas.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html

Comment: What command do you run? In what directory do you run that command? And what is in the firebase.json in that directory?

Answer (score 11):

If you're willing to have `/views/index.html` in your app's address bar, you could just do a redirect from `/` by adding a [`redirects`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html#section-redirects) element to your  `firebase.json`.  Also it looks like your `public` attribute may be incorrect.  So change your `firebase.json` file to:

```
{
  "firebase": "funmathgame",
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "redirects": [
    {
      "source": "/",
      "destination": "/views/index.html",
      "type": 302
    }
  ]
}
```

This way, any user who goes to https://funmathgame.firebaseapp.com/ will be redirected to https://funmathgame.firebaseapp.com/views/index.html and all relative URLs will be resolved correctly.

Comment: It is only fair that I award the bounty in full to you.

Comment: @RichardHamilton Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This was a difficult problem for sure. When you deploy to Firebase, Firebase is looking for an `index.html` file inside your public directory. This public directory is also known as the root directory.

I was working with an angular app, and I was simply using the wrong paths in my partials. This was pretty tricky though.

I had to set up an angular controller, that injected the `$document` dependency to get the title of a page. If the title of the page matched the title of the root page, I would use `ng-href` to prepend the `views` directory to the relative url.

Otherwise, if you were in the views directory, and searched for more views, it would show a path like `views/views/page1.html`. That's why we'd have a different `ng-href` conditional for these.

This is what my navigation looked like

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>

        <li><a ng-href="{{ page == home ? 'views/help.html' : 'help.html' }}">Help</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="{{ page == home ? 'views/achievements.html' : 'achievements.html' }}">Achievements</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="{{ page == home ? 'views/scores.html' : 'scores.html' }}">Scores</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="{{ page == home ? 'views/shop.html' : 'shop.html' }}">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="{{ page == home ? 'views/faq.html' : 'faq.html' }}">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="{{ page == home ? 'views/related.html': 'related.html' }}">More Games</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the end, my directory structure looked like this

```
public
  assets
    stylesheets
      styles.css
  views
    partials
      scripts.html
      header.html
      footer.html
    page1.html
    ...
  scripts
    controllers
    script1.js
    ...
  index.html
```

It is possible to place the index file inside the views directory as well, if you change the firebase.json file.

```
{
    "firebase": "firebase-app",
    "public": "root/views",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
}
```

You just change the public keyword in the firebase app. It took a lot of fiddling around, because I forgot I had to conditionally change the paths. Also, to navigate back into the previous directory you would have to do something like `../`

Answer (score 2):

I think this website may be of help to you: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-08-12-switching-to-firebase.html

Especially,

> Since Firebase imports a single file and some services export multiple files, I’ve created a handy python script that will convert multiple files to a single, Firebase sanitized file.